# How to animate a rectangular svg without any of it hidden outside of a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```css
svg {
  height: 50vh;
}

path {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  overflow: visible
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 844.5 464" style="enable-background:new 0 0 844.5 464;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#931D72;}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M316.8,316.7c-14.9,16.5-31.2,27-50.5,32.3l-0.2-0.5c-10.9,3.1-22.2,4.7-33.7,4.7
                c-66.9,0-121.2-54.4-121.2-121.2s54.4-121.2,121.2-121.2c34.6,0,66.9,14.5,89.9,39.9l13.1-10.9c-26.3-29.4-63.3-46.1-103-46.1
                c-76.2,0-138.2,62-138.2,138.2s62,138.2,138.2,138.2c40.7,0,70.6-13,97-42.1c25.7-28.4,44.4-68,64.2-109.9
                c15.6-33.1,31.7-67.1,52.3-97.3l0.4,0.3C485,59.6,551.3,22.9,623.6,22.9c59.7,0,116,25.2,155.7,69.5l13.1-10.8
                c-42.9-48.2-104-75.7-168.8-75.7c-67.3,0-121.4,23.5-165.5,71.9c-35.2,38.7-57.9,86.7-79.8,133.2
                C359,251.7,340.8,290.2,316.8,316.7z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M838.2,284.9c0-39.7-23.7-74-57.6-89.6c-0.8-0.8-1.7-1.4-2.8-1.9c-12-5-24.8-7.5-37.8-7.5
                c-54.7,0-99.2,44.5-99.2,99.2c0,22.2,7.3,43.4,20.8,60.7c-11.8,3.8-24.2,5.9-37,5.9c-66.7,0-120.9-54.3-120.9-120.9
                c0-39.3,18.8-74.2,47.9-96.3c20.2-14.9,45.1-23.8,72-23.8c33.4,0,65,13.7,87.9,37.7l0.9-0.8l12.2-10.1l0.9-0.8
                c-26.1-28-62.4-43.9-100.9-43.9c-10.9,0-21.5,1.3-31.7,3.7c-27.2,5.4-49.7,18.4-69.5,40c-1.8,1.9-3.5,4-5.2,6
                c-1.2,1.5-2.4,2.9-3.6,4.4c-0.5,0.6-0.9,1.2-1.4,1.8c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-19.7,25.7-36.2,59.2-55.1,99
                c-21.1,44.8-43,91-75.7,127.2c-26.2,29-56.4,48.2-91.3,57.9l-0.2-0.6c-18.8,5.4-38.3,8.2-58,8.2c-115.3,0-209.1-93.8-209.1-209.1
                S117.2,22.9,232.5,22.9c61,0,117.9,26,157.7,71.8l13.1-10.8c-43-49.7-104.7-77.9-170.8-77.9C107.8,5.9,6.3,107.3,6.3,232
                s101.4,226.1,226.1,226.1c65.8,0,118.9-23.2,162.1-71c12.2-13.4,22.8-28.1,32.5-43.4c18.1,31.8,43.7,58.8,74.7,78.7
                c36.4,23.4,78.5,35.7,121.9,35.7c91.1,0,172.8-54.2,208.3-138.1l-0.2-0.1C836,308.8,838.2,297,838.2,284.9z M623.6,441.1
                c-40.1,0-79-11.4-112.7-33c-31.4-20.2-56.8-48.2-73.7-81.3c13.2-23.1,24.6-47.3,35.9-71.1c4.1-8.8,8.2-17.3,12.3-25.6
                c0,0.6,0,1.2,0,1.9c0,76.2,62,138.2,138.2,138.2c48.8,0,93-24.9,118.2-66.5l-0.1-0.1c2.8-4.5,5.4-9.1,7.6-14
                c2-4.2,0.2-9.3-4.1-11.3c-4.2-2-9.3-0.2-11.3,4.1c-11.8,24.9-31.6,44.6-55.4,56.5c-13.2-14.9-20.5-34-20.5-54
                c0-44.9,36.6-81.5,81.5-81.5c44.9,0,81.5,36.6,81.5,81.5c0,11.1-2.2,21.9-6.6,32.1c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3
                C780.8,392.7,706.4,441.1,623.6,441.1z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

When this runs, because the SVG is rectangular, some of the rotation is hidden outside of the container.

How do I keep it all visible as this rectangle rotates?

Comment: Change the `viewbox`?

Comment: Obviously the first thing to do is make the box square and large enough to see the path at any rotated angle. Then make sure the group is centered in the box before rotating it about that center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of animating `path`, just do your transformation on the `svg` element. You also need to make sure your parent container is big enough to contain your rotating element so it doesn't get clipped. Then center it with absolute positioning and `translate()` in your animation:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: center-rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes center-rotate {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround:
apply `overflow:visible` property to your `<svg>` element.
The path won't be cropped but it might collide with surrounding elements.

As commented by Paulie_D: a cleaner approach is to adjust your viewBox to a square aspect ratio like  `viewBox="0 0 844.5 844.5"`.

Now you need to center your path vertically in the new viewBox.

You can convert your pathdata to all relative values using a tool like [svgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/). Since you're using only one fill color we can combine both paths to a compound path by *concatenating* the `d`attribute values.

This way we only need to change the first path command to move the complete shape. See also Lea Verou's post ["Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute commands"](https://lea.verou.me/blog/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/)

We can calculate the appropriate x and y offsets like so

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')
let path = svg.querySelector('path')

// get bounding box
let {
  x,
  y,
  width,
  height
} = path.getBBox();
console.log('bbox:', x, y, width, height)

// get svg viewBox
let vB = svg.viewBox.baseVal;

// calculate x/y offsets to center path in viewBox
let offsetY = vB.height / 2 - (y + height / 2)
let offsetX = vB.width / 2 - (x + width / 2)
console.log('offsetX:',offsetX, 'offsetY:', offsetY)
```

```css
svg {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 844.5 844.5" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#931D72;}
</style>
            <path class="st0" d="m 316.8 316.7 c -14.9 16.5 -31.2 27 -50.5 32.3 l -0.2 -0.5 c -10.9 3.1 -22.2 4.7 -33.7 4.7 c -66.9 0 -121.2 -54.4 -121.2 -121.2 s 54.4 -121.2 121.2 -121.2 c 34.6 0 66.9 14.5 89.9 39.9 l 13.1 -10.9 c -26.3 -29.4 -63.3 -46.1 -103 -46.1 c -76.2 0 -138.2 62 -138.2 138.2 s 62 138.2 138.2 138.2 c 40.7 0 70.6 -13 97 -42.1 c 25.7 -28.4 44.4 -68 64.2 -109.9 c 15.6 -33.1 31.7 -67.1 52.3 -97.3 l 0.4 0.3 c 38.7 -61.5 105 -98.2 177.3 -98.2 c 59.7 0 116 25.2 155.7 69.5 l 13.1 -10.8 c -42.9 -48.2 -104 -75.7 -168.8 -75.7 c -67.3 0 -121.4 23.5 -165.5 71.9 c -35.2 38.7 -57.9 86.7 -79.8 133.2 c -19.3 40.7 -37.5 79.2 -61.5 105.7 z m 521.4 -31.8 c 0 -39.7 -23.7 -74 -57.6 -89.6 c -0.8 -0.8 -1.7 -1.4 -2.8 -1.9 c -12 -5 -24.8 -7.5 -37.8 -7.5 c -54.7 0 -99.2 44.5 -99.2 99.2 c 0 22.2 7.3 43.4 20.8 60.7 c -11.8 3.8 -24.2 5.9 -37 5.9 c -66.7 0 -120.9 -54.3 -120.9 -120.9 c 0 -39.3 18.8 -74.2 47.9 -96.3 c 20.2 -14.9 45.1 -23.8 72 -23.8 c 33.4 0 65 13.7 87.9 37.7 l 0.9 -0.8 l 12.2 -10.1 l 0.9 -0.8 c -26.1 -28 -62.4 -43.9 -100.9 -43.9 c -10.9 0 -21.5 1.3 -31.7 3.7 c -27.2 5.4 -49.7 18.4 -69.5 40 c -1.8 1.9 -3.5 4 -5.2 6 c -1.2 1.5 -2.4 2.9 -3.6 4.4 c -0.5 0.6 -0.9 1.2 -1.4 1.8 c -0.2 0.2 -0.3 0.4 -0.5 0.6 c -19.7 25.7 -36.2 59.2 -55.1 99 c -21.1 44.8 -43 91 -75.7 127.2 c -26.2 29 -56.4 48.2 -91.3 57.9 l -0.2 -0.6 c -18.8 5.4 -38.3 8.2 -58 8.2 c -115.3 0 -209.1 -93.8 -209.1 -209.1 s 93.9 -209 209.2 -209 c 61 0 117.9 26 157.7 71.8 l 13.1 -10.8 c -43 -49.7 -104.7 -77.9 -170.8 -77.9 c -124.7 -0.1 -226.2 101.3 -226.2 226 s 101.4 226.1 226.1 226.1 c 65.8 0 118.9 -23.2 162.1 -71 c 12.2 -13.4 22.8 -28.1 32.5 -43.4 c 18.1 31.8 43.7 58.8 74.7 78.7 c 36.4 23.4 78.5 35.7 121.9 35.7 c 91.1 0 172.8 -54.2 208.3 -138.1 l -0.2 -0.1 c 4.3 -11.1 6.5 -22.9 6.5 -35 z m -214.6 156.2 c -40.1 0 -79 -11.4 -112.7 -33 c -31.4 -20.2 -56.8 -48.2 -73.7 -81.3 c 13.2 -23.1 24.6 -47.3 35.9 -71.1 c 4.1 -8.8 8.2 -17.3 12.3 -25.6 c 0 0.6 0 1.2 0 1.9 c 0 76.2 62 138.2 138.2 138.2 c 48.8 0 93 -24.9 118.2 -66.5 l -0.1 -0.1 c 2.8 -4.5 5.4 -9.1 7.6 -14 c 2 -4.2 0.2 -9.3 -4.1 -11.3 c -4.2 -2 -9.3 -0.2 -11.3 4.1 c -11.8 24.9 -31.6 44.6 -55.4 56.5 c -13.2 -14.9 -20.5 -34 -20.5 -54 c 0 -44.9 36.6 -81.5 81.5 -81.5 c 44.9 0 81.5 36.6 81.5 81.5 c 0 11.1 -2.2 21.9 -6.6 32.1 c 0 0.1 -0.1 0.2 -0.1 0.3 c -33.5 75.4 -107.9 123.8 -190.7 123.8 z"/>
  

</svg>
```

We get these offset values

```
x: 0.000091552734375 , y:190.2499542236328
```

Eventually, we change the path's first (`M`) command values like so:

```
M 316.8 506.95 //(316.7+190.25)
```

```css
svg {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

path {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 844.5 844.5" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#931D72;}
</style>
            <path id="path" class="st0" d="M 316.8 506.95 c -14.9 16.5 -31.2 27 -50.5 32.3 l -0.2 -0.5 c -10.9 3.1 -22.2 4.7 -33.7 4.7 c -66.9 0 -121.2 -54.4 -121.2 -121.2 s 54.4 -121.2 121.2 -121.2 c 34.6 0 66.9 14.5 89.9 39.9 l 13.1 -10.9 c -26.3 -29.4 -63.3 -46.1 -103 -46.1 c -76.2 0 -138.2 62 -138.2 138.2 s 62 138.2 138.2 138.2 c 40.7 0 70.6 -13 97 -42.1 c 25.7 -28.4 44.4 -68 64.2 -109.9 c 15.6 -33.1 31.7 -67.1 52.3 -97.3 l 0.4 0.3 c 38.7 -61.5 105 -98.2 177.3 -98.2 c 59.7 0 116 25.2 155.7 69.5 l 13.1 -10.8 c -42.9 -48.2 -104 -75.7 -168.8 -75.7 c -67.3 0 -121.4 23.5 -165.5 71.9 c -35.2 38.7 -57.9 86.7 -79.8 133.2 c -19.3 40.7 -37.5 79.2 -61.5 105.7 z m 521.4 -31.8 c 0 -39.7 -23.7 -74 -57.6 -89.6 c -0.8 -0.8 -1.7 -1.4 -2.8 -1.9 c -12 -5 -24.8 -7.5 -37.8 -7.5 c -54.7 0 -99.2 44.5 -99.2 99.2 c 0 22.2 7.3 43.4 20.8 60.7 c -11.8 3.8 -24.2 5.9 -37 5.9 c -66.7 0 -120.9 -54.3 -120.9 -120.9 c 0 -39.3 18.8 -74.2 47.9 -96.3 c 20.2 -14.9 45.1 -23.8 72 -23.8 c 33.4 0 65 13.7 87.9 37.7 l 0.9 -0.8 l 12.2 -10.1 l 0.9 -0.8 c -26.1 -28 -62.4 -43.9 -100.9 -43.9 c -10.9 0 -21.5 1.3 -31.7 3.7 c -27.2 5.4 -49.7 18.4 -69.5 40 c -1.8 1.9 -3.5 4 -5.2 6 c -1.2 1.5 -2.4 2.9 -3.6 4.4 c -0.5 0.6 -0.9 1.2 -1.4 1.8 c -0.2 0.2 -0.3 0.4 -0.5 0.6 c -19.7 25.7 -36.2 59.2 -55.1 99 c -21.1 44.8 -43 91 -75.7 127.2 c -26.2 29 -56.4 48.2 -91.3 57.9 l -0.2 -0.6 c -18.8 5.4 -38.3 8.2 -58 8.2 c -115.3 0 -209.1 -93.8 -209.1 -209.1 s 93.9 -209 209.2 -209 c 61 0 117.9 26 157.7 71.8 l 13.1 -10.8 c -43 -49.7 -104.7 -77.9 -170.8 -77.9 c -124.7 -0.1 -226.2 101.3 -226.2 226 s 101.4 226.1 226.1 226.1 c 65.8 0 118.9 -23.2 162.1 -71 c 12.2 -13.4 22.8 -28.1 32.5 -43.4 c 18.1 31.8 43.7 58.8 74.7 78.7 c 36.4 23.4 78.5 35.7 121.9 35.7 c 91.1 0 172.8 -54.2 208.3 -138.1 l -0.2 -0.1 c 4.3 -11.1 6.5 -22.9 6.5 -35 z m -214.6 156.2 c -40.1 0 -79 -11.4 -112.7 -33 c -31.4 -20.2 -56.8 -48.2 -73.7 -81.3 c 13.2 -23.1 24.6 -47.3 35.9 -71.1 c 4.1 -8.8 8.2 -17.3 12.3 -25.6 c 0 0.6 0 1.2 0 1.9 c 0 76.2 62 138.2 138.2 138.2 c 48.8 0 93 -24.9 118.2 -66.5 l -0.1 -0.1 c 2.8 -4.5 5.4 -9.1 7.6 -14 c 2 -4.2 0.2 -9.3 -4.1 -11.3 c -4.2 -2 -9.3 -0.2 -11.3 4.1 c -11.8 24.9 -31.6 44.6 -55.4 56.5 c -13.2 -14.9 -20.5 -34 -20.5 -54 c 0 -44.9 36.6 -81.5 81.5 -81.5 c 44.9 0 81.5 36.6 81.5 81.5 c 0 11.1 -2.2 21.9 -6.6 32.1 c 0 0.1 -0.1 0.2 -0.1 0.3 c -33.5 75.4 -107.9 123.8 -190.7 123.8 z"/>
  
</svg>
```